# Create specific orthogonal vector

Tags: vectors

I've been working on a project where my computer takes the X, Y, and Z accelerometer data from a wii remote and turns it into mouse movement. I'm fairly solid on all of my python, but I'm stuck on a bit of vector math. The setup is fairly tedious, so please bear with me.

The axes of the wii remote are as follows:

- +x axis : left side
- +y axis : face up (the side with buttons)
- +z axis : back (the side with the nunchuk port)

I'm creating a vector **V** = < x, y, z> where x, y, and z are the accelerometer outputs. This vector points up in the real world regardless of how the wii remote is oriented, so when the script starts and the wii-remote is face up, **V** = <0, 9.81, 0>.

If I use the Direct Angle formula (alpha = acos(a/||**V**||)) to find the distance from **V** to the y-axis, effectively giving me how far up the wii-remote is pointed, regardless of roll.

I need to find a vector **U** such that **U** is always orthogonal to **V** in such a way that when **V** = <0, 9.81, 0>, **U** = <9.81, 0, 0>, so that if I can find the angle between **U** and the x-axis, I can find how far *left* the wii remote is pointing, *regardless of roll.*

*note: I've tried **U** = < y,-x, 0>, but that weirds out on me and only gives me a vector on the XY plane.

*note 2: The vector **V** always points up. I'm looking for a vector **U** that always points left.

**TL;DR:** Given **V** = < x, y, z>, find **U** such that if **V** = <0, 1, 0>, **U** = <1, 0, 0>

Comment: why not just use $U = <y, 0, 0>$ when $V = <0,y,0>$?

Comment: because the vector will change over time. If I did that, the resulting vector would just be the y-component of the vector pointing to the x-axis. I need a different vector that is always orthogonal to **V**, with that rule as its starting point.